# Why do std::istringstream only work here with a constructor?

Tags: c++, istringstream

The code below compiles and works as expected. On line 11, when I change
`std::istringstream iss(temp)`
to
`std::istringstream iss()`
, it stops working. An error occurs on line 18, `iss.str(temp)`:
`expression must have class type but it has type "std::istringstream (*)()"`

Why would a change to the constructor make a difference? I checked the [docs](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/), it shouldn't make a difference, but I must be missing something. Any thoughts?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    int n, m;
    std::string temp;
    std::vector<int> ranked, player;
    std::istringstream iss();

    // Get the Input

    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
    n = std::stoi(temp);
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
    iss.str(temp);
    while(!iss.eof()) {
        std::getline(iss, temp, ' ');
        ranked.push_back(std::stoi(temp));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "Most Vexing Parse" - if an expression *can* be interpreted as a function declaration, then it *will* be so interpreted.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
std::istringstream iss();
```

is a declaration of a function `iss`. Remove the `()` to declare an object.

Also note that your usage of `while(!iss.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). The loop should be:

```cpp
while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
    ranked.push_back(std::stoi(temp));
}
```

Comment: I saw something like the loop you mentioned in other posts, but I looked at the documentation (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) and the return value didn't say anything about a boolean, so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

`std::istringstream iss()` is the declaration of function with name `iss` and return value `std::istringstream`.